# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: bluetooth, 21.04

This is the output from the `service bluetooth status` command:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Apr 26 14:35:17 a****i-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx systemd[1]: Condition check resulted>
Apr 26 14:38:57 a****i-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx systemd[1]: Condition check resulted>
Apr 26 14:40:51 a****i-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx systemd[1]: Condition check resulted>
lines 1-8/8 (END)
```

How do I get my Bluetooth to work?

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

this worked for me in Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting it?
`service bluetooth restart`
I had the same issue after the new upgrade, though status was showing active, but bluetooth wasn't working..

Comment: Thank you i tried service bluetooth restart and my settings still showing no bluetooth found

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem whereby Bluetooth was not turning on. 
This fixed it: `service bluetooth restart`

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1337388/

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in `bluez` package. **It has been fixed** in:

- version 5.56-0ubuntu4.2+ on *Ubuntu 21.04*; and
- version 5.53-0ubuntu3.3+ on *Ubuntu 20.04 LTS*.

See [comment #16](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1933221/comments/16) and [#18](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1933221/comments/18) on [Bug #1933221](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1933221) for details.

Just upgrade your system (or `bluez` package only) to fix the problem:

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt full-upgrade # or
$ sudo apt --only-upgrade install bluez
```

Answer (score 1):

Power off your PC and start again, make sure you remove the charging cable.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1859592/comments/2

This works for me.

Comment: This isn't enough information, what Bluetooth hardware are you installing? If this works please edit in comments and explain how and why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

that helped for me (ubuntu 21.04)

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez`

need to edit this file (I use editor vim, you can use another one)

2. `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bluetooth-ubuntu-bluez-hirsute.list`

replace `hirsute` to `bionic` and save

3)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

after that need to restart ubuntu and turn on bluetooth in settings again

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Ubuntu on to my Raspberry Pi 4 (8GB). But I hate wires, so I want to connect my BT keyboard and mouse. However I get the [Please plug in dongle] message when I open by BT settings.

I have also tried updating the software and firmware as well as commands such as

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
service bluetooth restart
```

when I run

`service bluetooth service`

I get

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-09-10 17:22:56 BST; 36min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1155 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8964)
     Memory: 1.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1155 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 10 17:22:56 rob-R****1 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Sep 10 17:22:56 rob-R****1 bluetoothd[1155]: Bluetooth daemon 5.56
Sep 10 17:22:56 rob-R****1 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Sep 10 17:22:56 rob-R****1 bluetoothd[1155]: Starting SDP server
Sep 10 17:22:57 rob-R****1 bluetoothd[1155]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized
```

I have tried all of the above to no avial.

I've also noticed that a log of the config files are empty? Is this normal? I only figured this out when I overclocked the CPU.

Comment: Please, this seems to be a question. Kindly post one if it is the case. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1168684)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an audio device sending audio from my old Harmon Kardon amp (a Logitech bluetooth transmitter) to a bluetooth dongle in one of my USB ports.  The symptom was a connection-disconnection cycle about every three seconds.  Really annoying.  After doing the restart didn't fix it, I removed the dongle and deleted the device from the bluetooth manager (blueman-applet), hit the pairing button on the transmitter, reinstalled the dongle, and all now worked.  I hope this low-tech advice helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did:

Opened Bluetooth settings and switched on the toggle, then restarted the service (in terminal):

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Hope that helps folks out.  Don't quite know why it doesn't work on startup. You could always add a restart for that service in your .bashrc (which isn't as efficient, but it's late and I'm too tired to think more).

Comment: This is nearly the same as a previous answer.